# Win32 menu item alignment

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I've generated a default Win32 app in Visual Studio and my menu looks like this

[image]

How do I make the menu items left-aligned to the menu item instead of right-aligned? Thanks.

Comment: We can only guess how you coded your program

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *default Win32 app*

Comment: Doesn't look like that here ......

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Probably is a setting on your PC and has nothing to do with the building of a Win32 application.  What about other applications and windows?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Windows 8.1, I suspect that's the only factor that could affect the app

Comment: The behavior is the same on Win7 and Win8/8.1. It is due the 'Handedness' setting. Please find the answer and solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **'Handedness'** setting has become corrupted or changed. To change this, follow these steps.

1. Press the Windows logo **key+R** to bring up the **Run** dialog box. In the
   **Open** line, copy/paste the following line of text:
   *shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}*
2. Press **OK**.
3. This will start the **Tablet PC Settings** configuration dialog (Even if
   you do not have a Tablet PC).
4. Select the **Other** Tab.
5. In the Handedness section, place a check mark in the **Left Handed**
   option.
6. Click **OK**.

Answer (score 2):

SystemParametersInfo, SPI_GET/SETMENUDROPALIGMENT